# Rails not creating intermediary table? - Habtm relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, sqlite, has-and-belongs-to-many

The table between the `User` model and `Period` model does not exist. They have a has_many_and_belongs_to relationship. I'm learning Rails still, so please bear with me.

This is the contents of the User.rb model file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :assignments, :order => "end"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :periods
end
```

This is the contents of the Period.rb model file

```
class Period < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weights
  has_many :assignments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

The exact error message is `Could not find table 'periods_users'`. This occurs when an instance of Period or User tries to invoke users or periods (i.e `new_user.periods` or `new_period.users`)

I'm using SQLite 3 for the development database, and SQLite 3 is properly installed.

**I presumed that Rails would create the intermediary tables for habtm relationships. Do I have to create them myself, and if so, how?**

(Please note that the other models associations are working just fine)

If I'm not giving enough information please let me know.

### edit: After trying Method B, it threw:

```
undefined method "klass" for nil:NilClass
```

This occurred while trying to manage the `User` and `Period` models in rails_admin

So, I deleted the new model, and tried Method A. It threw

`undefined method "period_id" for <ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQlite3Adapter:0x3df7760>`

while trying to run

`rake db:migrate`

Here is the migration:

```
class CreateTablePeriodsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table 'periods_users' do |t|
      t.integer period_id
      t.integer user_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table 'periods_users'
  end
end
```

### edit #2

Now it's having a `"create_has_and_belongs_to_many_reflection: Primary Key is not allowed in a has_and_belongs_to_many join table"`

This occurred after trying to run "rails server", and  before that I ran `rake db:migrate` successfully

### edit #3:

I fixed this a little less than a week ago, it ended up being an issue with the database schema, so I just dropped the database and re-migrated and it worked fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create them yourself yes, there's two ways you can do this.

a) Simply create a migration with a new table.

b) Create a new model to use for the HABTM association (this makes things like deleting an association easier).

**Method A:**

```
$ rails generate migration CreateTablePeriodsUsers
```

Then edit the newly generated migration file,

```
class CreateTablePeriodsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  def up
    create_table 'periods_users' do |t|
      t.integer :period_id
      t.integer :user_id
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table 'periods_users'
  end
end
```

Run `rake db:migrate` and you should be setup.

**Method B:**

```
$ rails generate model PeriodsToUser period_id:integer user_id:integer
```

Edit the PeriodsToUsers model

```
class PeriodToUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :period
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then change your models to use the `:through` option.

```
class Period < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :users, :through => :period_to_user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :periods, :through => :period_to_user
end
```

Ryan Bates has a nice example of this method on his website, https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts/blob/master/app/models/tagging.rb

Comment: That did it, but I'm having a really strange error now. I think it's something wrong with rails_admin but the error is "undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass" It looks like a typo, as this is the latest version from git, but I didn't see any typos in the method that was referenced ("NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#list", specifically in list). This error only happens with Period and User, which would probably mean that it doesn't support :through associations, but I will look that up.

Comment: @Indebi Er, is this error related to this question? Please code new source code etc

Comment: Updated my answer, those two column names should be symbols.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Edit: Migration was successful, but it's having a new error, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to created has_many_belongs_to_many relationship using **has_many** clause with *through* option follow the steps below:

1. Create table one (for example: users)
2. Create table two (for example: roles)
3. Create the following migration:

> rails generate model RolesToUsers user:belongs_to role:belongs_to

where *RolesToUsers* can be any name, and *user* and *role* are not in plural (the actual table names are *users* and *roles* - in plural).

So, the something like the following migration should be created:

```
class RolesToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :roles_to_users do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :role

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :roles_to_users, :user_id
    add_index :roles_to_users, :role_id
  end
end
```

with the corresponding model:

```
class RolesToUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

Finally, you only need to add the **has_many** clause with *through* option in the two models as follows:

In the *users.rb* file:

```
has_many :roles_to_users
has_many :roles, through: :roles_to_users
```

In the *roles.rb* file:

```
has_many :roles_to_users
has_many :users, through: :roles_to_users
```