# Unable to delete "has_and_belongs_to_many" connected records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have two models - *Users* and *Roles*. They are associated as follows:

In *user.rb*

```
...
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
...
```

In *role.rb*

```
...
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
...
```

So, a user can have many roles and a role can be associated with many users.

In order to set default values for roles (because each user should be created with at least one role) I have added the following code in my *seed.rb* file and run *db:seed* command:

```
roles = [
    Admin: 'test',
    Student: 'test'
]

roles.each do |role, description|
  SecurityUsersRole.find_or_create_by_role_and_description(role,description)
end
```

The roles are created but I  am not able to destroy them - this is the returned error message:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /security_users_roles/2

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704,
SQLERRMC=DB2INST1.SECURITY_USERS_SECURITY_USERS_ROLES, DRIVER=3.65.77: 

SELECT security_users.* 
FROM security_users 
INNER JOIN security_users_security_users_roles 
  ON security_users.id = security_users_security_users_roles.security_user_id 
WHERE security_users_security_users_roles.security_users_role_id = 2
```

The statement above should not return any records as I have not created any users yet, and associated them with roles.

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end of [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many) section in the official documentation it is said:

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many
>   :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model
>   as an independent entity. If you don’t need to do anything with the
>   relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a
>   has_and_belongs_to_many relationship **(though you’ll need to remember
>   to create the joining table in the database)**.

And that was causing the issue - I have not created the join table. If you need more details about how to created this intermediate join table look [Rails not creating intermediary table? - Habtm relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418955/rails-not-creating-intermediary-table-habtm-relationship/17284872#17284872)